# jQuery's .append() not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I get this trouble when I try to append some HTML to a div element. In Firefox (34.0.5) works fine, but not in Internet Explorer 8.
I found some solutions in SO but they didn't work out very well.
What I'm doing is calling a JS function from a Combo box onchange event:

```
<select id="ddlCantidadImagenes" name="ddlCantidadImagenes" onchange="CargarDivIngreso(value)" style="margin: 2px; float: left">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
```

Then, the function gets the value from the Combo box and use it in a switch statement.
Every case appends HTML code, here's an example:

```
case "1":
        {
            $('#ddlImagenes').hide();
            $("div").remove(".removable");

            for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(seleccion); i++) {
                $("#idPanel").append(
                '<div class="removable">' +
                '<div style="float: left; width: 530px; margin-top: 4px;">' +
                '<div style="width: 75px; margin: 2px; float: left;">' +
                '<label>' +
                'Desktop</label>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<input class="obligatorioImagen" type="text" id="tbImagenDesktop' + i + '" name="tbImagenDesktop' + i + '" style="margin: 2px;' +
                'width: 165px; float: left;" /><a href="#" id="btnBuscarPrincipal" style="margin: 2px; float: left;">' +
                '<img src="../_Imgs/ElegirH.png" alt="" style="border-style: none; border-width: 0px;' +
                'border-color: White;" /></a>' +
                '</div>' + 
                '<div style="float: left; width: 530px; margin-top: 4px;">' +
                '<div style="width: 75px; margin: 2px; float: left;">' +
                '<label>' +
                'Mobile</label>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<input class="obligatorioImagen" type="text" id="tbImagenMobile' + i + '" name="tbImagenMobile' + i + '" style="margin: 2px;' +
                'width: 165px; float: left;" /><a href="#" id="btnBuscarThumbnail" style="margin: 2px; float: left;">' +
                '<img src="../_Imgs/ElegirH.png" alt="" style="border-style: none; border-width: 0px;' +
                'border-color: White;" /></a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div style="float: left; width: 530px; margin-top: 4px;">' +
                '<div style="width: 75px; margin: 2px; float: left;">' +
                '<label>' +
                'Tablet</label>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<input class="obligatorioImagen" type="text" id="tbImagenTablet' + i + '" name="tbImagenTablet' + i + '" style="margin: 2px;' +
                'width: 165px; float: left;" /><a href="#" id="A1" style="margin: 2px; float: left;">' +
                '<img src="../_Imgs/ElegirH.png" alt="" style="border-style: none; border-width: 0px;' +
                'border-color: White;" /></a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div style="float: left; width: 530px; margin-top: 4px;">' +
                '<div style="width: 75px; margin: 2px; float: left;">' +
                '<label>' +
                'Url</label>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<input type="text" id="tbUrl' + i + '" name="tbUrl' + i + '" style="margin: 2px;' +
                'width: 165px; float: left;" /><label id="mensajeUrl" runat="server" style="font-size:12px; color:Red; font-weight:bold; margin-top:100px"></label>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>'
            );

            }

            break;
        }
```

Note: "seleccion" is the value of the combo.

At first, I thought that it was the "onchange()" event that was causing me trouble. But it wasn't that, and it reaches the JS part. In fact, I debugged it and it reaches the .append() function, without throwing any error. But nothing happens.
I hope you can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure why you have the braces inside the case statement. That looks like invalid JS to me, or at least I've never seen a switch statement use them before.

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using? `2.x` doesn't support IE8, you need to use `1.x`

Comment: I agree with @Alex, not sure what that might do to the code I've never seen that syntax and don't believe it's valid.

Comment: @Alex This is technically valid - it just creates a [block of code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#No_block_scope). But it does not add any value, such as scoping like it might in other languages.

Comment: @Rhumborl: Javascript does not have block scope, so it's probably invalid syntax.

Comment: Also, you should add `, 10` to your `ParseInt` as it defaults to octal and not decimal (aka `parseInt(seleccion, 10)`). Also, set it after `var i = 0` (as in `for(var i = 0, length = parseInt(seleccion); i < length; i++)`, then you dont need to run parseInt every time you loop, although that is unrelated to your problem)

Comment: @Cory No that's not invalid syntax, just irrelevant one

Comment: @BrunoMamani - what does parseInt Print on the console of IE8?

Comment: First: thanks to everyone for your answers.
As I said before, it works in Firefox. I debugged this in IE8 and it works. The For statement loops one time, and it reaches the ".append()" part. But it just doesn't append anything to the div ("#idPanel") element. So that's not the problem.

Comment: Btw, I'm using jQuery v1.8.3.

Comment: Well, I figured it out. It was an additional </div> that was closing no tag. So, yes, I hate IE8.

Comment: @BrunoMamani You hate IE 8 because you had invalid markup? :) That doesn't seem very fair. Glad you were able to resolve the issue though.

Comment: JK, but yes I hate it a little bit. Thanks to everyone for your time!